# Getting error using Forkjoin post methods

Tags: javascript, angular, fork-join

When I am using ForkJoin getting below Error:  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I want to send multiple post requests at a time using ForkJoin in Angular.

```
fetch_details(res){
var requests_list = [];
if(res == 1){
let request = this.http.post('BankDetailsUpdate', bank_params );
        requests_list.push(request);
}
if(res == 2){
let request = this.http.post('PersonalDetailsUpdate', bank_params );
        requests_list.push(request);
}

 this.save_details(requests_list);
}

save_details(requests_list){
          if(this.rejectedDetailsForm.valid){
            forkJoin(requests_list).subscribe(results => {
              console.log(results, "results");
            },
            error => console.log("Error: ", error),
            () =>{
     });
     }
    }
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error:  TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

what I am missing here? Can you please help

Comment: there may be cyclic reference of object

Comment: Hi, its not a `ForkJoin ` error, I think in your application, in `html` pages some where you have print array so that's why its breaking next compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed, issue was in those observable list there is incorrect value, like instead of using formcontrolname.value I have used formcontrolname directly, so because of that cyclic error occurred.

Thanks for the support, i hope this issue might be helpful to someone else.